# Type mismatch -- works in F# interactive, but not in a real F# project

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I can do this in F# interactive, and it works fine:

```
> printf "%d\n" 5;;
5
val it : unit = ()
```

But if I do the same thing in a "real" F# project:

```
let main argv =
    printf "%d\n" 5
```

I get this error when I try to compile:

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'a -> int    
but given a
    'a -> unit    
The type 'int' does not match the type 'unit'
```

Wrapping the statement in `ignore()` or piping it to ignore ( `|> ignore`) doesn't work, either.

This is a semantic error, but I have no idea how to reason about it, and google didn't help.

Why does it work in F# interactive and not in an actual F# project, and why is it semantically wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume your `main` function has the `EntryPoint` attribute.

F# (like most languages) requires main to return an int.

Just add `0` at the end of main.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it. *facepalm* I will accept the answer as soon as the 10 minutes are up. Coming from primarily a Java and C# background, main doesn't typically return any value.

Comment: @rianjs Actually, in C#, main can return either int or void.  If it returns int, the value is passed back to the OS as the process return code.  F# doesn't support the void option.

Answer (score 5):

As John Palmer said, the [entry point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402151.aspx) function has a type `string array -> int`, so the last line has to be `int`.

However, you don't need F# program to have an entry point function. You just need to have your code on the last `.fs` file in your project like this.

[image]